# Intersect boolean in animation doesn't render properly and gives blackout/whiteout

Tags: rendering, animation, modifiers, error

I'm creating an animation where a plane moves leftwards with a boolean intersect modifier, whereby only the intersect will show as shown in image 1.

[image]

image 1: frame 75, perfectly normal

However, this is not the case through the animation. What happens at (what i presume to be) random keyframes is a black or white boolean cube. This anomaly shows up in my video renders as well, as shown here:

[image]
image 2: frame 95, blackout

[image]
image 3: frame 128, whiteout

my question is, what the hell is going on and how do i fix it

Comment: Hello, there is an option in the boolean modifier, try toggling between "Exact" and "Fast" and see if it changes anything. Also, boolean does not work well with non-manifold meshes (eg a plane) Try adding a solidify modifier with a very low value

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the help, changing the value from "Exact" to "Fast" seemed to do it. Not only did it solve my problem, it also increased the frame rate drastically. Could you instead type this as an answer so i can mark it as solution to close this thread? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recent version an "Exact" mode has been added to the boolean modifier. It is enabled by default, and it is supposed to handle non-manifold and co-planar meshes better than the regular "Fast", mode, but it is also computationally very heavy and there are still edge cases where it fails.

You can try to toggle between "Exact" and "Fast" and see if it changes anything.

Also, booleans do not work well with non-manifold meshes (eg a plane) You can try adding a solidify modifier with a very low value.